# ElectronApp - Multiple Instances of Electron app under Task Manager and CPU utilized is 99%

Tags: reactjs, .net, electron

I have build electron app using ASP.NET Core with React.js template.
When I open the deployed app I can see multiple instances of app under task manager screenshot(MultipleInstancesTM.PNG)[MultipleInstances](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nC3qX.png) is this normal behaviour?

For the app I have used localDB (sqlite) and no external API request is made, It,s an offline app.

Electron app starts as follows :
Electron Socket IO Port: 8000
Electron Socket started on port 8000 at 127.0.0.1
ASP.NET Core Port: 8001
stdout: Use Electron Port: 8000

Stange issue I encountered is that when I open the app it makes local service call on port 8001 and to sqlite DB and I get response in milliseconds, For same request sometimes response time vary from few milliseconds to 5-10 seconds.
One thing I have noticed is that when response time takes time CPU utilization for app goes above 95% ~99% screenshot(99%usage.PNG)[99%usage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RGGrH.png).

I use "electronize build /target win" command to pack and deploy my app.

Am I missing something in configuration? Is there a way in which I can improve the CPU utilised by app so I get consistent response time?